# Python - how to import a class from a folder with a vertical bar in its name?

Tags: python, class, text, import, path

I'm trying to import a class from a folder called 'xxxx|yyy' and I'm getting an error because Python is not recognizing the vertical bar as part as the name of the folder:

```
from xxxx|yyy import Class
```

I tried setting up a variable called path, in which I wrote the name of the folder, to do the import, but it is not working as well:

```
path = 'xxxx|yyy'

from path import Class
```

Do any of you have any idea on how could I solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's your file structure? `xxx|yyy` is a directory (does it have to be named that?), but is `Class` a file or a folder with `__init__.py`?

Comment: You would have to use `importlib` to receive the file name as a string. `xxxx|yyyy` is a valid *filename*, but not a valid *identifier*.

Comment: While this can be done, it's really much better to change the module name. There are lots of things that expect identifiers to be, well, valid identifiers. Even if you get the import to work, various other things may break later on.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino xxx|yyy is the name of the directory. The folder structure would be: folder called "xxx|yyy" -> folder called "efficiency" -> __init__.py and files.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I am going to change the name of the module to avoid having problems.